# JPA @JoinColumn with extra condition on Parent class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api, criteriaquery

I spent almost all morning searching, but couldn't find any answer.

I have scenario where I have to JOIN with ManyToMany relationship with an couple of **extra conditions (on parent class)** to limit the rows for joins.

I'm looking for the association to generate the query on below lines.

```
Select * 
from User u
left outer join user_roles ur
      on u.user_id = ur.user_id
     and u.department in ('Sales', 'Services')
     and u.city in ('New york', 'london')
left outer join roles r
      on ur.role_id = r.role_id
where
// conditions
```

The department, city fields are in the parent class (User).

```
 ----------------
User.java

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", 
    joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
 private Set<Roles> roles;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "user_id")
 private Integer userId;

 @Column(name = "department")
 private String department;

 // other fields
 // setters and getters
 ---------------------------------

 Roles.java

 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

 //other fields
 //setters and getters

 --------------------------------
```

Also, the department names ('Sales', 'Services') along with city ('New York', 'London') need to parameterized. i.e., **these will change based on request**.

I tried using (1) @FilterDef (2) @WhereJoinTable  (3) @Where
None of them seem to work.

Comment: Have you looked at `@JoinFormula/@JoinColumnOrFomula`?

Comment: Yes, I have look at them as well.